# jQuery UI Effect breaks CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, ckeditor

Placing a jQuery UI effect on a parent div of a CKEditor instance seems to cause errors with the editor.  The text area will no longer be selectable and any buttons on the menu will cause the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getSelection' of undefined".

CKEditor will work fine with:

```
$('#toggle').toggle();
```

But will break when using:

```
$('#toggle').toggle('blind');
```

A jsfiddle showing the issue is here: http://jsfiddle.net/CZ3bS/

Are there any known fixes or work around for this issue??